# System hangs after Windows startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, freeze, hardware-failure

I have an Asus N61JQ laptop with Windows 8 Enterprise 64bit installed – same problems using Windows 7 X64 though.

Sometimes my Windows hangs when I shut it down by pressing the power button, and when I turn it on again, Windows hangs again. I mean windows starts up the after a short time then it hangs again!  I thought it's because of the temperature of the CPU or one of my hardware components, but although I'm now using CoolPad with 2 fans, the problem didn't resolve itself. I also reinstalled my OS many times.

I checked my system hard drive using Ubuntu's Disk Utility and there were no problems. I checked my RAM using Fedora's RAM troubleshooter and it said the RAM was OK.

After Windows started up I checked Event Log but there was just a log saying that Windows shut down unexpectedly. It gave no more details about system hang.

---

**Update**

I found out that my System hangs after installing an Optional (a Driver) Update. This is the name of the update:

`Qualcomm Atheros - LAN - Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)`

[this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/where-do-i-report-a-bug/3fdcaa2d-bbe3-4965-b880-03d35942eaed) is the question in microsoft answer

Comment: Does it hang if you shutdown from the operating system and NOT the power button?

Comment: @DaveM I've edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it's because of one of my system updates. the `Qualcomm Atheros Wireless Network Adapter` causes the problem (because it was for window 6.3 - windows 9?!?)

So I just hide it in windows update and I don't have such problems anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In device manager disable Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 **PCI-E** device

You will still be able to use wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I also have had nightmare problems with drivers of ASUS n61jq and windows 8 - starting from black screen ending with no wireless and bluetooth connection/driver functions (error code 52, could not uninstall from device manager with message "refused because required by descendants"), also problems with VPN and miniport drivers.

Finally I managed to fix all networking issues by setting drivers to:

LAN -> Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)

WLAN -> **Dell Wireless 1506 802.11.b|g|n**  (can be found by manually picking driver from Qualcomm Atheros Communication in device manager)

It's weird, but this Dell Wireless driver is only one working for me on ASUS running Windows 8.1